# Appium UITableview slows down automation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, automation, appium

I am trying to automate my native IOS application using Appium. I have a tableview with more than 1000 elements. When I try to select a cell from the tableview using Appium the entire process gets delayed and I can see in the appium console that the appium engine is iterating over the entire tableview items.

Here is the code I am using,

```
waitUntilElementBecomesClickable(element).click();


public WebElement waitUntilElementBecomesClickable(String element) throws Exception 
{
       return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name(element)));
    }
```

Is there any better way to click an element from the tableview(I dont want to use the XPath as my data is dynamic)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**You need to understand the Element Hierarchy as well as UI Element Accessibility.**

---

At the top of the element hierarchy is the UIATarget class, which represents the high-level user interface elements of the system under test (SUT)—that is, the device (or simulator) as well as the iOS and your app running on that device. For the purposes of your test, your app is the frontmost app (or target app), identified as follows:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp();
```

To reach the app window, the main window of your app, you would specify

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow();
```

---

**For Table:**

In the first table view in the app’s array of table views, so you specify it as such using the zero index ([0]), as follows:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0];
```

Inside the table view, each Item is represented by a distinct individual cell. You can specify individual cells in similar fashion. For example, using the zero index ([0]), you can specify the first cell as follows:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[0];
```

Each of these individual cell elements may designed to contain a  record as a custom child element. in this first cell the record f which you can access by name with this line of code

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[0].elements()["Record Name"];
```

In This way You Can Just Give The Cell Index To Reach A Specific Cell. Hope this is useful, Regards

[For More Info Use This Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH20-SW85)